# Exclude specific Select class form selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check if all `<select>` on the page, except the one that has the class "`lastDays`", do have 0 value.

I have tried this:

```
if ($('.dropFilter input').val()=='' && $('select[class!='lastDays']').val()==0){
...}
```

And this:

```
if ($('.dropFilter input').val()=='' && $('select').not('.lastDays').val()==0){
...}
```

None of the works, as when all select have 0 value, but "lastDays" has value 1, it does not execute operations inside the conditional.

EDIT: HTML piece:

```
<div class="dropFilterSelect">Sólo registros de: <select name="lastdays_select" class="filterOptionList lastDays"> <option value="0">Últimos 7 días</option> <option value="1">Últimos 15 días</option> <option value="2">Últimos 30 días</option><option value="3">Sin límite de días</option> </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropFilterSelect">Entre los días: <div style="width:70.5%; display: inline-block; float:right;"><input type="date" id="ar_fromDate" name="ar_fromDate" class="datepicker" value="" style="margin:2px 10px 3px 0; float:none; width:120px;"> y <input type="date" id="ar_toDate" name="ar_toDate" class="datepicker" value="" style="margin: 2px 0 3px 10px; float:none; width:120px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropFilterSelect">Horario:<select id="timetable_select" name="timetable_select" ><?php echo $turn_conf_filter_list; ?></select>
                                </div>
                            <div class="dropFilterSelect">Ciclo:<select id="cl_course" name="cl_course" ><?php echo $course_conf_filter_list; ?></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropFilterSelect">Asignatura:<select id="cl_subject" name="cl_subject" ><?php echo $subject_conf_filter_list; ?></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropFilterSelect">Clase:<select id="cl_class" name="cl_class" ><?php echo $class_conf_filter_list; ?></select>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please add your html to the question or a JSfiddle

Comment: you are calling .val() over a collection, it results in returning the value of the first one..!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, is there any way apart from .each to tell it to check the total amount of matched elements on the page? I am about to try with the .each method

Comment: what do you mean by ***under the class***? having the class or is contained in some element having the class?

Comment: @Biomehanika you can use `.filter()`..

Comment: is there only one select under the .lastDays?

Comment: Than you, i'll invest @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @AminJafari there is just one select with the "lastDays" class

Comment: @KingKing I have edited the post. I mean the element with the class "lastDays", tehers only one with that class

Comment: @shaunakde, edited and added HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do if all the inputs are siblings:

```
$('.lastDays').siblings('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=0){
        alert('not all zero');
        zero=false;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        zero=true;
    }
});
if(zero){
    alert('all zero');
}
```

if they're not siblings then tell me and I change it to the other way!

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I have just read. I solved this by other way, but anyway I've tried yours and it does not work as it does nothing, no alert is displayed.